# List tables from MySQL DB and display table names as options in a drop down list

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to write a page with 2 drop down lists. THe first populating a list of tables from mysql db allowing the user to choose the date in question, the second allowing the user to choose a name from a column in that table. I currently have the form written like below to generate an array of values from the specific table/row specified by the user which I can then echo out in to various fields in the html form.

I am struggling with getting the drop down list populated by the table names. Can anyone assist please? Sorry for the long post it's my first and I wanted to be thourough. I know that the connection to my database is working and the second drop down list is working when I specify in the code what table to use.

I need the first box to list the table names and then set the variable $date.

This is the drop down list for the date:

```
<select name='Date'>
<?php
    $date = $_POST['date'];
$cxn=mysqli_connect("localhost",$userid,$password,$db)
or die ("Could not connect to Database");

$result=mysqli_query($cxn,"Show tables from january");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
echo "<option value='".$row['Value']."'>".$row['Value']."</option>"; 
}

?>
</select>
```

This is the drop down list for the names from the table selected above.

```
<select name='agentname'>
<?php
    $name = $_POST['agentname'];
$cxn=mysqli_connect("localhost",$userid,$password,$db)
or die ("Could not connect to Database");

$sql=mysqli_query($cxn,"SELECT Value FROM january.'$date'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
{      
echo $value ="<option value='".$row['Value']."'>".$row['Value']."</option>"; 
}

?>
    </select>
     <input type='submit' value='Get Dashboard' />
</form>
```

Creating the form :

```
<form action='getlist.php' method='post'>
 <div align="center">
   <p>
     <select name='Date'>
<?php
    $date = $_POST['date'];
$cxn=mysqli_connect("localhost",$userid,$password,$db)
or die ("Could not connect to Database");

$result=mysqli_query($cxn,"Show tables from january");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) 
{
echo "<option value='".$row['Value']."'>".$row['Value']."</option>"; 
}

?>
</select>

<select name='agentname'>
<?php
    $name = $_POST['agentname'];
$cxn=mysqli_connect("localhost",$userid,$password,$db)
or die ("Could not connect to Database");

$sql=mysqli_query($cxn,"SELECT Value FROM january.'$date'"); //I have specified schema's in my DB for the different months 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) 
{      
echo $value ="<option value='".$row['Value']."'>".$row['Value']."</option>"; 
}

?>
    </select>
     <input type='submit' value='Get Dashboard' />
</form>
```

TO be used in the following query to generate the array:

```
<?php
$cxn=mysqli_connect("localhost",$userid,$password,$db)
or die ("Could not connect to Database");

$result=mysqli_query($cxn,"SELECT column1, column2, column3 //just listing examples here for my columns there is about 45 columns for this selection
FROM january.'$date' 
WHERE Value='$name'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
        $stats = $row;
}

?>
```

Comment: You create a database for every month and a table for every day?

Comment: It would be helpful to have an example database schema, as it seems you're doing something weird with your structure.

Comment: @digitalChris, Yes I have a schema for the month and a tables for each day.

Comment: @ethan, I haven't done that before how would you like to see it? I basically have a schema that is a month and tables in the schema for each day of the month with data for a list of people in rows and columns specifying what the data is.

Comment: So you create a database for every month and a table for every day?....why????

Comment: @ethan I think we both know why. user3199675 - This database schema is seriously flawed. I suggest consulting with someone experienced in RDBMS design, or going back and doing a lot of DB design research before continuing down this path.

Comment: the database schema works just fine. The data im storing is daily statistical data and needs to be viewable on a daily basis. I can with php query the tables directly using their names and it works just fine. My question is only how can I generate a drop down list of the tables that exist in the schema? Thats all I need to know if you can help thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright...

To address your actual question, I think the problem is the index you're referencing in the output of `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.  Generally, the table names of a "SHOW" query are keyed like "Tables_in_databasename", or something like that.  You might `print_r` your `$row` variable to see what index you should reference.

Now, unrelated to your questions, I do have to insist you rethink how you're storing your data.  It is very bad procedure to have meaningful data represented in the names of your databases and tables.  Not only is this not the way databases are meant to be used, which will inevitably cause problems for you, you're also making things unnecessarily hard for you.

I'm not sure what kind of statistics you're storing, but let's say it's something like clicks per day for a website.  This data can be very easily stored in one database, and one table.  For example:

Database: statistics

Table: daily_statistics

Columns: id, stat_date, value

Now you can store the clicks-per-day easily, and in one table.

```
id, stat_date, value
1, 2014-01-01, 300
2, 2014-01-02, 400
etc...
```

Let's say that you have multiple values per day.  Not a problem

```
id, stat_date, value
1, 2014-01-01, 300
2, 2014-01-02, 400
3, 2014-01-02, 250
etc...
// The unique ID, alows multiple records per day.
// If you need them categorized in a different way,
// add another column.
```

This structure will work for years and year to come.

```
id, stat_date, value
1, 2014-01-01, 300
2, 2014-01-02, 400
3, 2014-01-02, 250
4, 2015-01-01, 250
5, 2016-01-01, 250
etc...
```

Now you have access to mysql aggregating functions,you  have a situation where it will be easier to import and export data, you won't have to deal with having 100s of databases and even more tables as the years go on, and any developer who comes after you won't have to pull their hair out trying to work with this sticky situation.

Comment: Thank you Ethan! So your suggestion is that in 1 table in 1 db store the data as a date and then name with the stats for that day. then I can run my query on the db and let the user type in the date, pick the name and then use those 2 values to identify the correct row in the table?

Comment: So I could then using this structure say I wanted to see the average for a date range use the same query with multiple dates and use some function to average the values and display them in the array, yes?